# D3 force layout change showed links with slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a problem with this d3 force layout:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UJqNumlkl9rt8WGGOKYm?p=preview

I am trying to show only the links whose value is equal to the value of the slider. However it only works when loading the data, when I slide the slider it does nothing and I don't understand why. This is the code for changing the link width

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return d.value == slider.value() ? 3 : 0;
    });
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what you want to do, is to just update the link as the value of slider changes.

```
slider.on('slide', function(e,v) {
  updateLinks();
});

function updateLinks(){
  svg.selectAll(".link")
   .style("stroke-width", function(d) { 
     return d.value==slider.value() ? 3:0; 
  });
}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0uHFJ3bT6voO4cLFHrK?p=preview) is the plunker with solution